# Como validar si existe un usuario

Tags: javascript, html, login

La siguiente consulta pertenece a una api, donde solamente estoy validando si `id_user` ,`passsword_user`  existen.

```
 <?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
  require_once('../apis/connection.php');
/*OBTIENE USERS*/
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
{
  if(isset($_GET['id_user']) && isset($_GET['password_user']))
  {
    $id_user=$_GET["id_user"];
     $password_user=$_GET["password_user"];
     //$type_user=$_GET["type_user"];
     $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();

    $query = 'SELECT id_user,password_user,type_user from users where id_user = ? AND password_user= ?';
    $result=$connection->executeQuery($query, array($id_user,$password_user));

    if ($result>0)
    {
      $user = json_encode(array(
                'id_user' => $result[0][0],
                'password_user' => $result[0][1],
                'type_user' => $result[0][2]
              ));
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 0,
        'user' => json_decode($user)
        ));
    }//if
    else
    {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 1,
        'errorMessage' => 'user not found'
        ));
    }//else
  }
} //CIERRA IF
?>
```

Este es el resultado, Como se puede ver por ahora solo tengo un `user` en esta ocasión este es `admin`, así que tendrá accesos diferentes a algún otro.

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "user": {
        "id_user": "56012",
        "password_user": "123",
        "type_user": "admin"
    }
}
```

Este es mi `login`, y en el botón tiene un `onclick` que lleva a un `function` a `JS`:

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" id="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none" id="errorLogin">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-w-m btn-success" type="button" onclick="login()">LOGIN</button>
```

`Js`:

```
  function login(id_user,password_user)
{
    //debugger
    console.log('ENTRE A LOGIN');
    var id_user =document.getElementById("user").value;
    var password_user =document.getElementById("pass").value;
    //var type_user  ='admin';
    console.log(id_user);
    console.log(password_user);
    //console.log(type_user);
//validar que no esten en blanco
    if (id_user  === '' || password_user == '') {
        $("#id_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
        $("#password_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
        document.getElementById("errorLogin").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("errorLogin").innerHTML = "No puedes dejar campos en blanco, completa la informacion.";
        document.location.href="#errorLogin";
    }
    //si no estan en blanco avanza al ajax.
    else{
    var fd = new FormData();
                var data =  $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "apis/user.php?id_user="+id_user+"&password_user"+password_user,//A que archivo enviara los parametros
                 data: fd,//Parametros que se enviaran
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data){
                 var tipo_usuario = data.user.type_user;
                 console.log('ENTRE AJAX');
                 if(tipo_usuario == "admin")
                 {
                     console.log('entre if');
                        window.location.href='./article.html';
                 }
                 else if(tipo_usuario == "receipt")
                 {
                     window.location.href='./receipt.html';
                 }
                 else if(tipo_usuario == "output")
                 {
                     window.location.href='./output.html';
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     alert('usuario no existe');
                     return false;
                 }
                },
            }
    console.log(data);
//}
}
```

Como ven estoy recibiendo parámetros, un problema que tengo es que no se como identificar si es `admin`,otro problema que tengo es que parece que no esta validando si existe o no el usuario.

Con un Debugger, después de validar que los campos no estén en blancos, llega a `var data =     $.ajax({` y no entra a lo demas,asi es como se mira en la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo dar solución a esto, o tal vez es el `query`?

El error que me salta es:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type_user' of undefined

En la linea:

```
var tipo_usuario = data.user.type_user;
```

Comment: ¿Qué te devuelve el console.log de la respuesta de la api? ¿Devuelve undefined directamente o te devuelve la respuesta y solo es undefined el campo type_user?

Comment: Solamente Undefined.

Comment: Por que mejor no traes el `type_user` desde el método GET y no a través de la consulta **Query**. Creo que seria más fácil identificar a los usuarios con números, se facilita a la hora de la validación.

Comment: Como podria hacer eso, pudieras apoyarme.

Comment: Que tipo de Login manejas? Uno para todos los tipos de usuarios?

Comment: Asi es, y depende el tipo lo mandara a la pagina indicada.

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es que en el HTML agregues un radio button para que el Administrador lo clickee y ese tenga el valor de "1" y se lo pasas por el método GET igual que el ID y Password, ya con eso solo necesitas consultar si en la base de datos existe un usuario con ese ID donde el campo type_user sea igual a "1", claro para eso tendrías que agregar un nuevo campo en la base de datos para que los usuarios se identifiquen al momento de registrarse. No se si te sirva, te lo comento por que así es como manejo una App en Android y la idea es la misma.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos lo podrias hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "apis/user.php?id_user="+id_user+"&password_user"+password_user+"& type_user"+type_user,//A que archivo enviara los parametros
  data: fd,//Parametros que se enviaran
 processData: false,
 contentType: false,
 success: function(data){
  var tipo_usuario = data.user.type_user;
  if(tipo_usuario == 'admin'){
     window.location.href='./article.html'
  }else if(tipo_usuario == 'A')){
    window.location.href='./ejemploA.html'
  }else if(tipo_usuario == 'B'){
    window.location.href='./ejemploB.html'
  }else{
    alert('usuario no existe');
    return false;
  }
 },

}); //fin ajax
```

Si te fijas valido dentro del evento success que trae el resultado del llamado y mediante un if hago las validaciones pertinentes, ahora debes cambiar las validaciones porque nose si type_user es numero, text o que trae, debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Espero te sirva y guie..!!

Comment: Lo aplicare, te comentare que sucede.

Comment: claro..suerte !!

Comment: me sale este mensaje ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type_user' of undefined` en `var tipo_usuario = data.user.type_user;`. Hice unas modificaciones en el query, quitando el parámetro de type_user, al igual que en el JS, por que de igual con el select trae los 3 datos y puedo aplicar la misma comparación o eso creí por que de igual dice undefined.

Comment: @Pato podrias modificar tu pregunta para colocar el nuevo codigo como quedo y el error actual

Comment: Ya esta editado

Comment: fijate como traes los datos x console: data == "admin"...de esa manera validas pero en tu php no traes ello hacia ajax , x eso te coloque var tipo_usuario = data.user.type_user;

Comment: Igual sale Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type_user' of undefined

Comment: revisa por consola como traes el resultado de success en ajax..con console.log(data);

Answer (score 0):

En tu base de datos en la columna type_user ahi pon un enumerado que tenga todos los tipos de usuarios que quieres

y tu login solo envia usuario y contraseña

```
 url: "apis/user.php?id_user="+id_user+"&password_user"+password_user,//A que archivo enviara los parametros
```

en tu api

```
$query = 'SELECT id_user,password_user,type_user from users where id_user = ? AND password_user= ? ';

$usuario=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conexion,$query); //ejecutas tu query y guardas el resultado en $usuario

if($usuario){echo $usuario['type_user'];}else{die("error"); }
```

Ahora en tu ajax

```
success: function(r){
if(r == "admin"){window.location.href='./article.html';}
            else if(r=="tipoB") {window.location.href='./otrapagina.html'};
else{alert("Los datos son incorrectos");}
},
```

Comment: He hecho las modificaciones, en query, y puesto el codigo que me has dicho, ingreso el id_user y el password y dice que usuario no existe cuando es el unico registro que tengo en la BD y es correcto

Comment: Prueba cambiando la query en tu api asi

$query = "SELECT id_user,password_user,type_user from users where id_user = '$_GET[id_user]' AND password_user= '$_GET[password_user]' ";

Comment: Mismo error, intento poniendo data.user.type_user en el if, y dice que type_user es undefined.

Comment: Hay alguna forma de comparar en el query algo asi como, type_user = admin OR type_user= A.. y ponerlo ahora si como parametro? o mas bien como parametro no, pero que ahora si compare en los if y me mande al archivo correcto?

Comment: ese error es porque tu funcion tiene 3 parametros y cuando la mandas a llamar no le pasas ninguno 

quita los parametros de tu funcion y llamala asi $('.btn-success').click(function(){ y borras esto del button onclick="login()"

Comment: En mi functio JS hice los cambios, eso incluye quitar el parámetro de type_user :/

Answer (score -1):

Cuando recibes la respuesta de la api tienes que comprobar el dato que se recibe:

```
if (id_user  === '' || password_user == '') {
        $("#id_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
        $("#password_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
        document.getElementById("errorLogin").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("errorLogin").innerHTML = "No puedes dejar campos en blanco, completa la informacion.";
        document.location.href="#errorLogin";
    }
    //si no estan en blanco avanza al ajax.
    else{
    var fd = new FormData();
                var data = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "apis/user.php?id_user="+id_user+"&password_user"+password_user+"&type_user"+type_user,//A que archivo enviara los parametros
                    data: fd,//Parametros que se enviaran
                    success: function(data){ //Aquí devuelve el response

                      if(data.user.type_user == "admin"){
                         window.location.href='./article.html'; 
                      }else if(data.user.type_user == "A"){ //lo mismo para"B"
                          window.location.href='./ejemplo.html'
                      }
                        console.log(data.user.type_user);
                        //console.log('ENTRE AJAX');

                    },
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                }); //fin ajax
            }
    console.log(data);
//}
}
```

Comment: Parece que esta esperando como parametro el type_user, lo he quitado del query y del js, ya que con el select creo que lo debe de traer y solo hacer las comparaciones.. pero me dice que type_user es undefined.